# Assign entire array values to string without looping in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array about 1000 values, I've just shuffled them using shuffle(). Now I want to echo the shuffled results. But here's the catch, can it be done without looping through the array or displaying array 'syntax'?

ie:

```
<?php
    $myarray = array('a','b','c','d');
    shuffle($myarray);
    echo array_echo_vals_only($myarray);
    /*
    should echo: dbca
    */
?>
```

Comment: @LeviMorrison because loops are passé..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply Use `Implode`

```
echo implode($myarray);
```

Or Just reduce the array  with `array_reduce`

```
echo array_reduce($myarray, function($a,$b){$a .= $b; return $a;});
```

Play around with `vsprintf`

```
echo vsprintf(str_repeat("%s", count($myarray)), $myarray);
```

We also have some crazy ways ..

```
echo preg_replace("/\W/", "", json_encode($myarray));
```

Or

```
echo str_replace(array("]","[","\"",","), "", json_encode($array));
```

What i think ....

> Assign entire array values to string without looping in PHP

Loop is not a bad solution  .. you may as well give it a try ... Example :

```
$l = "";
$c = count($array);
for($i = 0; $i < $c; ++ $i) {
    $l .= $array[$i];
}
echo $l;
```

Comment: -1 for "benchmarking" this with a *seriously* dodgy "fastest" example (the `for` loop only iterates `0` to `4`).

Comment: @salathe seen it should just use `count` since m3 also uses `count`

Comment: Still, -1 for "benchmarking" this!

Comment: @salathe question is to blame, not the answer, IMHO.

Comment: The question didn't ask for benchmarks, just "can it be done…" Showing a variety of ways which don't use loops or show "array syntax" (print_r(), var_dump()?) is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use `implode`.

```
echo implode($array);
```

---

If you *do* care about speed... well...

I'm hoping I won't get a response like this:

> -1 for "benchmarking" this

**EDIT**: I did.

---

Through my "comprehensive test", `str_replace` is the fastest method.

### But no-one can prove it, and it can mangle the results.

```
str_replace(array(']', '[', '"', ','), '', json_encode($array));
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/odCTvDuR)

---

### So, for simplicity, stick to `implode`.

---

*Older, invalid test results:*
<del>But anyway, here is my test (I used some functions from @Baba's script for comparison): [codepad.org/BwBLpmgp](http://codepad.org/BwBLpmgp).</del>

<del>Result:</del>

<del>array_pop
Time: 0.0014219284057617

array_shift
Time: 0.00010895729064941

for loop
Time: 0.0004279613494873

vsprintf
Time: 0.00033998489379883

implode
Time: 0.00016212463378906

str_replace
Time: 0.0012540817260742</del>

<del>`array_shift` is the fasted method.</del>

<del>Usage:</del>

<del>while($shift = array_shift($array)) {
    $result .= $shift;
}</del>

Comment: It was pointed out that if the order is changed, the results change, so I'll create separate files for each test.

Comment: Don't bother; the question doesn't even hint at execution time being something of any importance, real or imagined.

Comment: @salathe I can't imagine this being done without loops even if there isn't any `for,foreach,do,while` shown (you tell me). This is either interview question, serious micro optimization, attempt of ninjafied code, or just plain stupid... Cheers.